# How to interpret "некого" in "чем от некого короля"?

Tags: значения

> От него гораздо больше толку, чем от **некого** короля!
>
> {my literal translation}: From him (we get) a lot more use than from a **certain** king.

The only meaning of the word "некого" that I'm aware of is "no one", but it seems like a bit of a stretch to apply this meaning here.

Incidentally, I have read that "некого" is the negative genitive of "кто". So is "некого" made up of "не" and "кого"?

Comment: [Related discussion](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5957/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5) (in Russian)

Comment: "No-one" is a possible translation for "н**и**кого", which is a different word.

Comment: @DK. Wiktionary indeed lists **некоего** as a correct form. I believed the form is as outdated  as "некоей" and "некоих". Ok.

Comment: In [Related discussion](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5957/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5/437715#437715) (In Russian) I've posted a complete paradigm for **некий**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This particular **некого** is unrelated to **кто**. It's from **некий**, which is basically a more bookish, slightly archaic **какой-то**.

Properly, the genitive should be **некоего**, but it's one of those quirks of inflection that a lot of people forget or never learn.

Here, the choice of **неко(е)го** over **какого-то** adds an undertone of scepticism or suspicion (a "some king" that stops just short of saying "some *supposed* king") whereas with **какого-то**, it would've been more outright dismissive ("some king... like those are ever any good").

EDIT: Ouch. I completely forgot — despite your translation — that **некий** can also have a different shade of meaning, close to **кое-какой**. So without context, it's hard to tell whether the speaker means "than some king" or, indeed, "than *a certain* king [we all know]".

Comment: Hi. Тhe context is: "than a certain king [we all know]".

Comment: @alone-Zee, Comment about некий (род. пад.): Грамматический словарь РЯ (Зализняк, 1980, стр. 58) says the standard form is *некоего*, then adds that _некого_ is possble but "в литературную норму еще не входит". Some search shows that modern dictionaries continue to hold the same view (treat _некоего_ as standard).